# Rigify Eye rotating out of socket!

Tags: rigify

when I turn the eye using the eye widget, my eyes seem to rotate out of their sockets. The eyes are big, but perfectly spherical. If I rotate both of them in object mode using individual origins as the pivot point in Z axis they rotate properly, but when rotating using rigify widget they get get out of the socket. I used Tiny eye for blender for my eyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened to me due to improper pivot point placement. First make sure that the eyes are spherical. If not they might bulge as they rotate, and I don't knw yet how to help you fix that. Tiny eye (Completely free very high quality eyes) is perfectly spherical in object mode, but it has the cornea bulge in edit mode. I selected the top-most and bottom-most vertices and set the 3D cursor to be between them. That was the eye's pivot point. Then go into the metarig, and just set the eye bone to that pivot point, then regenerate rig.
If you need a video to follow along, I recorded my process here: https://youtu.be/vkHRXL4I0qY

I posted the video and this question because I had nearly pulled my own hair out trying to figure this out. Googling didn't offer a solution. In hindsight it's a simple thing to solve, but this still might help out someone.